# Не могу отрисовать график

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Читаю книгу "Введение в машинное обучение". Там есть такой пример на `python`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import mglearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris_dataset = load_iris()
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris_dataset['data'], iris_dataset['target'], random_state=0)
iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)

pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(
    iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o', hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3
)
```

В конце должен отрисовываться графиик, но ничего не происходит. Согласно [документации](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) вроде все делаю правильно. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Добавьте в начале: %matplotlib inline

Comment: Вопрос скорее всего потерял актуальность, уже много лет как отрисовка в `jupyter notebook` не требует добавления `%matplotlib inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы где то забыли про plt

```
plt(pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(
    iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o', hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3
))
```

И да, дело говорит **MaxU**

"Добавьте в начале: 
**%matplotlib inline**
"

Comment: Pandas (alias `pd`) сам замечательно справляется с рисованием графиков, поэтому обертывание `plt()` является лишним...

Answer (score 0):

```py
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize=(10, 10),
marker='o', hist_kwds={'bins': 15}, s=40, alpha=0.8,)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ ничего не добавляет к вопросу. Просто немного другой дизайн графиков, по сути вы ничего не поменяли.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]